# VBA - Call function to each cell within a column using a Button

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

With the click of a button I want to apply a function to each individual cell in a column and output purely the results in another column. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Strategy:

Loop through entire column of A, starting at A1 until I hit an empty row. This will be the first loop in which there will be a counter telling me how many pieces of data are within the column,

Second loop applies pre-created function to each piece of data and outputs it to a different column.

I only just picked up VBA last week and I'm not entirely sure how I would do this.

Comment: What have you tried? Any code? What is the "pre-created function". When you apply the function do you want to retain the original data in Column A, Or do you want to apply the function in place?

Comment: it's a function that parses data from yahoo finance and outputs specific data into a cell.
        =yahooParse(A2)
        =yahooParse(A3), etc
but I want a button that calls all these functions and throws the output into the respective column that I define.

Comment: Yes, I want to retain the data from the original column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can at least get you started. More info and a better question will result in me providing you a better answer.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long

If Range("A1") <> vbNullString And Range("A2") <> vbNullString Then
    LastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row ' how many rows have data within the column
End If

With Range("B1:B" & LastRow) 'Last row in A so you know how many rows to use
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=yahooPage(RC[-1])"
    .Value = .Value 'Removes the formula and leaves only the values.
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: this seems like it would work. How would I add the changing cell into my function.
        YourFunctionHere(Range(???).Select)???

Comment: @user2140261 that should be `(RC[-1])`

Comment: @user2578013 Answer has been updated. When using R1C1 reference, you specify how many rows, and columns away from that current cell you want to recference. You should avoid Selecting any cell in VBA 1) It slows down your code. 2) It is usually the main cause of runtime errors. o in this Example I use -1 Because One row Before `B` is `A`, If the formula was in C we would use -2. D = -3 and so on.

Comment: @AndyG Opps, Thats the result of not using an editor to write code I suppose, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: `Method of 'Range' of Object;_Global failed'`
It doesn't like the line: `with Range...`
Any thoughts?

Comment: @user2578013 Without your code in front of me a shot in the dark would assume that you either Deleted or commented out `LastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row`. I just tested it and i didn't get any errors. So, without knowing what changed you made its hard to tell you whats wrong.

Comment: it fails the `if` statement and goes straight to the `endif`

Comment: there is data in both `A1` and `A2`

Comment: @user2578013 Updated my answer. Should be if the cells are NOT blank.

Comment: that seemed to do the trick!
this is my call: `.FormulaR1C1 = "=yahooPage(RC[-1])"' and now i'm getting `#NAME` in every cell in column B. my function takes in `strings` btw, if that helps. I can't chat you because I don't have enough reputation so I apologize for the poor communication.

Comment: `.FormulaR1C1 = yahooPage(Text(RC[-1]))`, `syntax error`, what stupid thing have i done now?

Comment: @user2578013 You forgot the double quotes. `.FormulaR1C1 = "yahooPage(Text(RC[-1]))"` I would probably change the function to Accept a range. And use the Value of the range that it accepts as in place of the text in accept though.

Comment: it prints: `yahooPage(Text(RC[-1]))` in every cell in col `B`

Comment: changing the function to accept a range is not possible as it would be heavily taxing on the system to have to go to a different website every cell in one succession and parse the html.

Comment: it literally prints what is in quotes.
somehow it's not calling my function with is defined as a `public function` above

Comment: @user2578013 I updated my code, It is working for me with a test function that adds one to the range. If it does not solve the answer then I am out of ideas as it seems to be working for me.

Comment: there is not a way i can purely get the text rather than the formula? `Text()` does not seem to work.

Comment: @user2578013 You could try `.FormulaR1C1 = "yahooPage(MID(RC[-1],1,LEN(RC[-1]))"`

Comment: That does not seem to work.
I've tried: `.FormulaR1C1 = "=yahooPage(MID(RC[-39],1,LEN(RC[-39]))"` and that didn't work either. Just printed the above in the cell.

Comment: `.Value2 = Evaluate("yahooPage(RC[-39])")` does not seem to work

Comment: but `'.Value2 = "=yahooPage(RC[-39])"` does the exact same things as `.FormulaR1C1 = ...`

Comment: The value of the reference cell? OR after the function return only the value?